# Facet Version Must be 5.0 - Using Javassist in Websphere

Tags: hibernate, websphere

I have a Websphere 6.1 EAR that I am trying to deploy and I am currently getting the following message when I add javassist-3.4.GA.jar to the EAR.

`Facet version for Enterprise Application project IntegrationEARProject must be 5.0 to contain Java EE 5.0 project lib //{path to file}/hibernate/R3_3_1/jars/javassist-3.4.GA.jar.`

Currently the Project Facets are set as folows:
EAR version is 1.4
Websphere version is 6.1

Please note that we do not have any of the feature packs installed currently and I do not have the option to install the feature packs.

Is there anything that can be done to get around this issue?  I am coding using java 1.5.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the project you are trying to use needs Java EE 5, and as you observe WAS 6.1 without feature packs will only support J2EE 1.4 even though the Java SE version itself is 5.

I'm not clear why javaassist cares which Java EE version it's used with, or whether there might be an earlier version usable with J2EE 1.4.

I fear that you may have to move up to WAS 7, which does support Java EE 5.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get around the problem I went ahead and downloaded the source and built the project myself.  When I added the project I built to the EAR I didn't encounter the same problems as the JAR from the Javassist web site.  I have tested the jar I built in my test and QA regions without any problems to date.